# Is replacing dynamic AND with Like search ok?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-like, dynamicquery

I want a MYSQL query to be generated during compile time. There are some AND clauses which I want to them to dynamically append to the query based on the optional input parameters, which will be known during runtime.

So I plan to have a LIKE search instead of dynamically  concatenating AND.

Imagine I have a value called 'Ramakrishna',the query looks like

```
  SELECT * from my_table WHERE col LIKE '%Ramakrishna%'
```

And when there is no value for the parameter I would like to use like search

```
  SELECT * from my_table WHERE col LIKE '%%'
```

I want to do it for 15 parameters in my query.
      I don't want to do it for a huge query, unless I know the performance trend of this method.
Is it going to be very costly ?

Comment: Why not generate where claused based on input parameter ?

Comment: the preparation of the query isn't a slow point. Its the execution of a full table scan. A proper full text implementation solr/lucene for searches will search a better performance gain.

Comment: @user9920500 . . . I don't understand the question.  What results do you want?  How are the other 14 columns/parameters being used?  Actually, your question mentions "parameters" but the query doesn't use any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Build the query dynamically.  Period.

- By constructing the query, you will include optimizations that the Optimizer may miss.
- The overhead of the query construction may be less than MySQL's effort to parse and Optimizer the query.
- Be aware that `LIKE` with a leading wild card is un-optimizable.  Ponder ways to avoid it.
- Have a few multi-column ("composite") indexes to help with the columns that are commonly searched for.  *This will be the best optimization.*

Answer (score 0):

if  you can create dictionary with 15 parameters, then

```
with par as (
      select name_par
      from params
     )
select *
from my_table, par
where col LIKE par.name_par
```

Comment: . . Have you ever heard of `JOIN`?  You should use it in your answers.